# People picker rendered incorrectly in SharePoint 2010 with custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, peoplepicker, sharepointfoundation2010

I have a list with couple of person fields. There is a page which allows to enter these values, but the people picker on that page is rendered incorrectly. It renders correctly if we use the default v4.master.

[image: People picker rendered incorrectly.]

Can anybody please let me know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a javascript which was changing the class on the textareas on the page so that it can auto grow. That was causing the issue.

Removed that line and it sloved the issue.

Thanks.